# android application version code update not working in blackberry

Tags: android, blackberry

I have developed an android application and installed apk in Blackberry and android devices.

The first time installation works fine.

When i try to update for next release i changed 'android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0.0"' to 'android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0.1"' in android manifest file.

Its working fine in android devices, but in blackberry the update is not working getting "Installed application is lastest".

Note: The application is not released from playstore.

Answer (score 0):

Increment the version code also. I'm actually surprised that it worked in Android. Google Play Store won't let you upload an updated app unless the version code is "greater".